# How to assert a method has been called from another complex method in Python?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am adding some tests to existing not so test friendly code, as title suggest, I need to test if the complex method actually calls another method, eg.

```py
class SomeView(...):
    def verify_permission(self, ...):
        # some logic to verify permission
        ...

    def get(self, ...):
        # some codes here I am not interested in this test case
        ...
        
        if some condition:
            self.verify_permission(...)
        
        # some other codes here I am not interested in this test case
        ...
```

I need to write some test cases to verify `self.verify_permission` is called when condition is met.

Do I need to mock all the way to the point of where `self.verify_permission` is executed? Or I need to refactor the `def get()` function to abstract out the code to become more test friendly?

Comment: You patch the method with a [Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). The Mock has a built-in counter.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? Maybe as answer?

Comment: Yeah, you would mock out the stuff before. It's not usually necessary to mock out everything, only things that are problematic to call during test e.g. network requests. With experience, you would usually end up writing the tests at the same time as developing the code, so that you don't find yourself in the situation of needing to add tests to "not so test friendly" code. There's not that much value to adding tests to existing code IMO, the point is to write code and tests _together_. Knowing that you have to test the code actually influences how you structure the code at the time of writing.

Comment: I don't think there is anyway, you will have to patch the code before & the code after `verify_permission` call if they involve other call or have long time operation. But I think this is what you already known...

Comment: @atline There is actually a hacky trick to avoid patching the code _after_ - you mock `verify_permission` with a side effect to raise an exception. Then you assert on the call + exception. I'm not sure if it's recommendable, but it is possible..

Comment: @wim Yes, this skill (the exception after the code) looks really great, I never think we could do it like that, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @wim yeah that's something I was thinking of earlier, but not sure if there is a shinny mock feature that I was not aware of so I don't have to go the hacky way...

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of points made in the comments that I strongly disagree with, but to your actual question first.

This is a very common scenario. The suggested approach with the standard library's `unittest` package is to utilize the [`Mock.assert_called...`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called) methods.

I added some fake logic to your example code, just so that we can actually test it.

`code.py`

```py
class SomeView:
    def verify_permission(self, arg: str) -> None:
        # some logic to verify permission
        print(self, f"verify_permission({arg=}=")

    def get(self, arg: int) -> int:
        # some codes here I am not interested in this test case
        ...
        some_condition = True if arg % 2 == 0 else False
        ...
        if some_condition:
            self.verify_permission(str(arg))
        # some other codes here I am not interested in this test case
        ...
        return arg * 2
```

`test.py`

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from . import code

class SomeViewTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_verify_permission(self) -> None:
        ...

    @patch.object(code.SomeView, "verify_permission")
    def test_get(self, mock_verify_permission: MagicMock) -> None:
        obj = code.SomeView()

        # Odd `arg`:
        arg, expected_output = 3, 6

        output = obj.get(arg)
        self.assertEqual(expected_output, output)
        mock_verify_permission.assert_not_called()

        # Even `arg`:
        arg, expected_output = 2, 4

        output = obj.get(arg)
        self.assertEqual(expected_output, output)
        mock_verify_permission.assert_called_once_with(str(arg))
```

You use a `patch` variant as a decorator to inject a `MagicMock` instance to replace the actual `verify_permission` method for the duration of the entire test method. In this example that method has no return value, just a side effect (the `print`). Thus, we just need to check *if* it was called *under the correct conditions*.

In the example, the condition depends directly on the `arg` passed to `get`, but this will obviously be different in your actual use case. But this can always be adapted. Since the fake example of `get` has exactly two branches, the test method calls it twice to traverse both of them.

---

When doing **unit** tests, you should *always* isolate the unit (i.e. function) under testing from all *your* other functions. That means, if your `get` method calls other methods of `SomeView` or any other functions you wrote yourself, those **should** be mocked out during `test_get`.

You want your test of `get` to be completely agnostic to the logic inside `verify_permission` or any other of your functions used inside `get`. Those are tested separately. You assume they work "as advertised" for the duration of `test_get` and by replacing them with `Mock` instances you control exactly how they behave **in relation to `get`**.

Note that the point about mocking out "network requests" and the like is *completely unrelated*. That is an entirely different but equally valid use of mocking.

Basically, you 1.) *always* mock your own functions and 2.) *usually* mock external/built-in functions with side effects (like e.g. network or disk I/O). That is it.

---

Also, writing tests for existing code **absolutely has** value. Of course it is better to write tests alongside your code. But sometimes you are just put in charge of maintaining a bunch of existing code that has no tests. If you want/can/are allowed to, you can refactor the existing code and write your tests in sync with that. But if not, it is still better to add tests retroactively than to have **no tests** at all for that code.

And if you write your unit tests properly, they still do their job, if you or someone else later decides to change something about the code. If the change breaks your tests, you'll notice.

As for the exception hack to interrupt the tested method early... Sure, if you want. It's lazy and calls into question the whole point of writing tests, but you do you.

No, seriously, that is a horrible approach. Why on earth would you test just part of a function? If you are already writing a test for it, you may as well cover it to the end. And if it is so complex that it has dozens of branches and/or calls 10 or 20 other custom functions, then yes, you should definitely refactor it.